# Javascript cannot test for null appropiately

Tags: javascript

This code fails and I have no idea why:

```
  var responsable = $("#tgresponsable").val();

  console.log(responsable);

  if (responsable){  
    // Do nothing
  }
  else{
    postMessage("No se puede crear un grupo de tareas sin responsable. Si no es coordinador de algún proyecto no podrá crear grupos de tareas",true,"msg_cont");
    return;    
  }

  console.log("Responsable is " + responsable)
```

This prints out:

```
null
Responsable is null
```

I have tried all of these:

```
if (responsable == null)
if (responsable === null)
if (!responsable)
```

And they ALL fail to catch the null value. Cany one tell me how to properly test for a null variable in javascript?

Comment: If `null` is the value of that id, then `null` is a _string_, and it has a truthy value which is why the condition is not working the way you want.

Comment: in console the `null == null` `null === null` and `!null` gives `true`. definitely you are getting not a `null` or there is something wrong with your browser

Comment: I bet `if (responsable == "null")` is true

Comment: Impossible, `if (responsable)` and `if (!responsable)` do the exact opposite thing, so one of them must work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$("#tgresponsable").val()` is not set the function should return `undefined`, not `null`. So here I am guessing that `$("#tgresponsable").val()` is actually set to the string `'null'`.
Try testing with:

```
if (responsable === 'null')
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Since I was used to the field returning null when there is nothing selected it never occurred to me that the actual value was the string "null".

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you shared, if the code is not printing the else part then definitely the value of responsible is not null. What must be happening is you will be getting a string value "null" getting returned from  `$("#tgresponsable").val();`

this will print "null" as o/p of -->  console.log(responsable);

Had the value been set to undefined, its o/p won't show "null" but "undefined " in `console.log(responsable);`

Will suggest you to check what value is getting retuned from    `("#tgresponsable").val();`

Now when you want to test the null variable you can just write

```
   if (responsable === 'null') {
       //will enter here if value is not null
    } else {
       //will enter here if value is null
    }
```

Hope this answers what you were asking.